# How to script a database migration using SSH?

Tags: ssh, shell-script, mysql

I am trying to create a `sync.sh` script that coordinates with our less-than-ideal version control for our website.  This script will migrate a copy of the live database to our local development environment and a couple other things.  I'm having trouble with the mysql migration portion.

This script is run on a development machine.  `remote` is the live host.

```
# --------------
# database

# ssh tunnel
ssh -L 3307:remote:3306 user@remote

# mysql dump
mysqldump -u someuser -h remote -P 3307 -p"p4ssw0rd" db > localfile.sql

# somehow close ssh tunnel ???

# populate local db with sql dump file
mysql -ulocal db < localfile.sql

# -----------------
# other sync stuff
# ...
```

When I just run the mysql portion of the script, I'm getting this output:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Enter password:
```

We have ssh keys setup and I can ssh to the remote properly.  However, when run in the script context, things are going wrong.

Comment: Note: using the same data in development environment is not the best idea especially when there are some sensitive data in your database like users passwords or users private data. There was few examples when that kind of data leaked from development servers as there was no security at all at devs machines...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it in one line without the tunnel using something like:

```
$ ssh user@remote "mysqldump -u user --password=password database_name" | 
  mysql -u local database_name
```

Comment: Holy toledo! this is awesome, thank you :)